# Link error: How do I run CPLEX java example in macos?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, cplex

Am I missing anyting e.g escape char, '/', that would cause this linkage error?

Command:

```sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java \
  -Djava.library.path=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/  \
  -classpath /Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/opl/examples/opl_interfaces/java/customdatasource/out/production/customdatasource:/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/opl/lib/oplall.jar \
  customdatasource.CustomDataSource
```

Java version : adoptopenjdk-11.jdk

Error:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/opl/bin/x86-64_osx/  -classpath /Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/opl/examples/opl_interfaces/java/customdatasource/out/production/customdatasource:/Applications/CPLEX_Studio_Community201/opl/lib/oplall.jar customdatasource.CustomDataSource
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.swig_module_init()V
        at ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
        at ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.<clinit>(concert_wrapJNI.java:1623)
        at ilog.concert.cppimpl.IloEnv.<init>(IloEnv.java:49)
        at ilog.opl.IloOplFactory.<init>(IloOplFactory.java:84)
        at customdatasource.CustomDataSource.main(CustomDataSource.java:159)
```

Cplex libraries in macos:
[image]

Just for some context:
[image]

Rant (please ignore) :

The IBM OPAL IDE is of horrible quality and keeps crashing in macos - so I prefer running these examples in command line.

The examples are so old-style, with ant, and seem not updated for quite a long time! I wish they changed examples to use maven so I can run directly from cmdline or intellij

Comment: Why can’t you run Ant directly from the command line? Most modern IDEs support Ant too.

Comment: At a guess, the native libraries you have don’t match exactly the Java library you have.